# Can't Connect To Mac App Store Through Proxifier

Tags: macos, proxy, socks

Hi for some reason proxifier won't allow my Macbook to connect to things such as Mac App Store, iMessage, XCode, Mail, Siri. Is there any way to fix this? All help is greatly appreciated!

[Here are my proxy rules.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iVyv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please move the second rule to the top and edit it to delete the special port,That means the connect can direct through when the connect math the ip address whatever any ports. Second make sure your socks server work well.